# Does bounded version of Lagrange's 4-square theorem follow from this result?

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, asymptotics, sums-of-squares

Let $S_4(n)$ be the number of ways of representing $n$ as a sum of 4 integer squares and suppose I can give you a proof of the result that $\sum_{i=1}^nS_4(i) \sim \frac{\pi^2}{2}n^2$.

Is this result enough to deduce that beyond some $N$, every integer can be represented as the sum of 4 squares (given that we are "weakly" suggesting that $\sum_{i=1}^nS_4(i) >> n$)?

Comment: It's not true that $S_4(n)\sim\frac{\pi^2}{2}n^2$. What is true is that $\sum_{k=1}^nS_4(k)\sim\frac{\pi^2}{2}n^2$.

Comment: Ah yes, I meant that! Let me just update this.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: Can you answer the question, though? I know from experience on this site that you're quite a capable individual...

Comment: You need more than that asymptotic.